# Counting the number of tuples $(i,i',k,k')$ satisfying some conditions

Tags: self-study, asymptotics, combinatorics

I'm struggling to find the cardinality of a set that will be presented below, as well as an upper bound for it. It is an engaging problem and perhaps not trivial.

I will give now the baseline of the problem.

Consider the discrete interval $A_T=\{1,2,\dotsc,T\}$ and the points $p_{s,k}=s+(k-1)\theta$, where $s\in \{1,\dotsc,\theta\}, k\in \mathbb{N}$, and the period $\theta \in \{1,\dotsc, \Theta_T\}$. So, as $T \rightarrow \infty$, the number of possible choices of $\theta$ diverges so that $\Theta_T=o(T^{2/5})$ (i.e., at a slower rate). Note that, any point $i$ in $\{1,\dotsc, T\}$ can be associated to a point $s\in \{1,\dotsc,\theta\}$ by the function $s(i)=i-\left \lfloor{\frac{i-1}{\theta}}\right \rfloor \theta$. Therefore, $i$ and $s(i)$ are both in $\{p_{s(i),k}\}_{k=1}^{K_{s(i),T}}, \forall i\in A_T$, where $K_{s,T}$ is the cardinality of the intersection $\{p_{s,k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \cap \{1,\dotsc, T\}$. It can be shown that $K_{s,T}$ is either $\left \lfloor{\frac{T}{\theta}}\right \rfloor$ or $\left \lfloor{\frac{T}{\theta}}\right \rfloor +1,\forall s\in \{1,\dotsc, \theta\}$, and hence is $O(T/\theta)$.

Finally, consider the following concept: say that an index $i_1$ is separated from other indices $i_2,\cdots,id$ if $\mid i_1-i_k \mid >C\log{T}, k=2,\dotsc,d$ and $C$ a finite constant.

Now, I'm going to state the problem.

Define $\Gamma$ as the set of tuples $(i,i',k,k')$ such that none of $i,i',s(i)+(k-1)\theta,s(i')+(k'-1)\theta$ is separated from the others, and $i,i'\in A_T, k\in \{1,\dotsc,K_{s(i,T)}\}, k'\in \{1,\dotsc,K_{s(i',T)}\}$. **Determine the cardinality of the set $\Gamma$ or an upper bound for this cardinality**.

An upper bound for #$\Gamma$ is $C_1(T\log{T})^2$ although I don't know how to argue that precisely. There must be a scheme to count these points which are "close" from each other (i.e., not separated) along $A_T$.

If you think it is easier, **what is the cardinality of the complement $\Gamma^c$ or an upper bound for this cardinality**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is more suited to Math.SE I think where you have already asked.